# Nextjs dynamic routes return 404 in production but not in localhost

Tags: next.js, netlify

i'm trying to learn how dynamic routes work with NextJS and the thing is that in localhost (`npm run dev`) works fine, but as soon as I push it to production in Netlify I get 404 error. Static pages are working, it just happends with dynamic routes. Here is an example of the code I have (is just a simple, static json to test how it works):

```
function ArticleListByCategory({articles}){
    
return(
    <>
    <h1>{JSON.stringify(articles)}</h1>
    </>
)
}
export default ArticleListByCategory

export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    const {params} = context
    const {category} = params
    return {
        props:{
            articles:{
                "news":[
                    {
                        "name":"article1",
                        "category":category
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

install[@netlify/plugin-nextjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@netlify/plugin-nextjs)

add `netlify.toml` in your root directory

```
[build]
publish = ".next"

[[plugins]]
package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"
```

package.json

```
"next": "^12.1.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

Here's a working example Nextjs SSR with netlify. https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-9rssk1

Live preview https://capable-medovik-a6ec0b.netlify.app/